# Django remove source files and how to running pyc files?

Tags: python, django, pyc

In Django project, I don't share the views.py to client. like to remove views.py source files from Django, only pyc files there. But when i remove source file, it gives me ImportError, it should refer pyc file, but it is not refering them. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Greetings, baliao! Just to make sure, you are not importing your files a views.py but just views, correct? Trying to import the package as an .py file might be causing the error.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I'd like to remove all of  *.py source code and leave pyc file, how to make it running Django with pyc?

Comment: Could you show us the folder structure of your project? What are the names of the .pyc files, where are they located relative to the files which are importing those and so on. You gave literally almost zero details.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, confuse everybody a lot, I fixed the problem like this:

1. python -m compileall path/to/project
2. python manage.pyc runserver, we can run Django even removed the source code (*.py)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).